# Body text is outside the box

Tags: bug, android-app

The body text is outside the box in the Android application.

For example:

[image]

I use a Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900A with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Nexus 5 on Android 4.4.4 here. In reproduce this although the body label is slightly more centred but still not as much as the other two.